# Split string with delimiter having more than one characters

Tags: c, split

For example, if the input string is "abcbba" and I want to split string at "bb", I will get two tokens "abc" and "a".

For those of you want to suggest strtok function. The strtok function only splits at one character. Say if I do:

```
char my_string[] = "abcbba";
strtok(my_string, "bb");
```

The tokens will be "a", "c", and "a".

Comment: Could you please make the question clearer? What is the use of this program/function? Why does it split it exactly in that way?

Comment: In C, `''` is used to represent a character. `'bb'` is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `strstr()`.

```
char my_string[] = "abcbba";
const char delim[] = "bb";
char *ptr = my_string;
char *next_delim = NULL;
while((next_delim = strstr(ptr, delim)) != NULL) {
    *next_delim = '\0';
    // Token at ptr
    ptr = next_delim + sizeof(delim) - 1;
}
```